# keylistener messing up program

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, key

i am using the NetBeans GUI builder. when i add a key listener in the apropreate space, the whole program goes haywire. it says "class or enum expected" i think it is the problem with the parentheses. here is my code

```
package chess;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addInputMethodListener(new java.awt.event.InputMethodListener() {
            public void caretPositionChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {
                formCaretPositionChanged(evt);
            }
            public void inputMethodTextChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {
            }
        });
        addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                formKeyPressed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");

        jTextField2.setText("jTextField1");

        jTextField3.setText("jTextField1");
        jTextField3.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                jTextField3KeyPressed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("move to");

        jLabel2.setText("move from");

        jLabel3.setText("output:");

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Century Gothic", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("press \"p\" to procede");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(49, 49, 49)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(77, 77, 77)
                        .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(60, 60, 60)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addGap(113, 113, 113)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(82, 82, 82)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(56, 56, 56)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 287, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(57, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addGap(10, 10, 10)))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addGap(56, 56, 56)
                .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(77, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void formCaretPositionChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                         

    private void jTextField3KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                      

    private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}// every thing after this goes hay wire
    }                               

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Please show your complete error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line never compiles..

```
private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}// every thing after this goes hay wire
}
```

You have to write your code there instead.

Here you are adding the keyListener and calling a private method.

```
addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            formKeyPressed(evt);
        }
    });
```

This is the private method then you have write your implementation.

```
 private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
    //write  your implementation of keypressed here..
 }
```

**By the way (most important), just you are learning i recommend you not to use netbeans matisse, read swing tutorials from oracle, for example [Using Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) and [How to use Keybindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)**

Comment: thanks but your answer is some what unclear, how should i wright it?

Comment: @GheraKuznetsov write what? `formKeyPressed`? just as you do usually with other methods

Comment: @GheraKuznetsov _how should i wright_ Not at all in this form - the most important part of this answer is the very last sentence (too small compared to the rest, unfortunately). As much as Netbeans builder will nudge you into the wrong direction, **don't** follow it!

Comment: @GheraKuznetsov you should be able to use mattise when you understand the code that generates

Comment: no problem, you already _did_ mention the correct way to do it :-) Just want to emphasize the fact for @GheraKuznetsov

Comment: @kleopatra http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17626760/gridlayout-not-filling-jpanel/17626773#comment25663237_17626773 i really want you to read this discussion to see what you think

Comment: @nachokk funny, Hover wants it also :-) Don't understand your argument with composition, though: be prepared to explain that to me - will post an answer in that QA for the sake to clarify _my_ take on your discussion

Comment: @kleopatra i was thinking that if he wants that, he should use private class with declarative name and should override `setPreferredSize` throwing `UnsopportedException` but also he could break some parent contract cause concrete inheritance if you don't use properly have this things

Comment: Ow well ideceded butuns and mouse preesed would be better for my purpose.